# webpack dynamic import: How to change the default signal "~" in file name?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, dynamic-import

I am using **Vue.js** to build a web app. And **webpack** (version: 4.41.2) is my build tool, and I am using dynamic import way t load component, a simple definition is as below:

```
components: {
  chat: () => import(import(/* webpackChunkName: "chat" */ './chat')),
  file: () => import(import(/* webpackChunkName: "file" */ './file'))
}
```

The webpack output config is :

```
output: {
  filename: 'js/[name].[chunkhash].js',
  chunkFilename: 'js/[name].[chunkhash].js'
},
```

Below are built out files:

```
chat.ed11dfebe7589449a58f.js,
file.5d49ceb7951cfdd60f32.js,
chat~file.9626240163418cbf81b9.js
```

As you see, there is a file with name `chat~file`, In our company security rule, if file name contains `~` , will block to download them, so I need to change the signal `~` here to other allowed signal like `_`, does any one know how to change this in webpack config ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Config name delimiter by `optimization.splitChunks.automaticNameDelimiter = '_'`

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#optimizationsplitchunks

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the names of the generated chunks with the `vue.config.js` file.
Try with this:

```js
module.exports {
  configureWebpack: (config) => {
      config.output.filename = '[name].[hash:8].js';
      config.output.chunkFilename = '[name].[hash:8].js';
  }
}
```

**EDIT because comment:**

Can change delimiter with `automaticNameDelimiter` (check [documentation](http://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/%E2%80%A6)).

Comment: I am using the same config here, I have added the output section in the question description. The 'chat~file.hash.js' includes the common logic between chat component and file component, so the webpack define the chunk name as 'chat~file', what I wonder is how to redefine this name.

Comment: Check this documentation: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#splitchunksautomaticnamedelimiter
With this option you can change delimiter character